# What is `RepositoryMock.Verify` doing

Tags: c#, moq

Could you please help me with the following.

I'm working on a Unit Test Project using C#, MSTest and Moq and if I want to verify if a method is called I use:

```
RepositoryMock.Verify(x=>x.method(int value).Times.Once());
```

My question is: will the `RepositoryMock.Verify` be evaluated in order to check if my test will pass or fail? I mean, is like an assert that if the method is never called then the test will fail or what happens, what is the final result if the method is never called?

Comment: Why don't you try? ;)

Comment: what s your research?

Comment: I agree with @Bv202 - I reckon you'd be able to try this out to see what happens quicker than the time it took to ask the question :-)

Comment: Wow, I'm on a meeting for the time being that's why I don't have the opportunity to test, just wanted a simple answer, some people is fantastic...

Comment: _what is the final result if the method is never called?_ if the method is never called then its never executed and there is no result.

Comment: Sorry, I answered for RhinoMocks. Are you sure that you are using Moq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Verify` is part of the old syntax, the one before AAA. In the old days, you set up a mock in "record mode", then ran the test in "replay mode", then verified all expectations by calling `Verify`. If you didn't call it, the expectations were not verified (there is also a `VerifyAll` to verify all mocks at once).

You don't need it in AAA anymore. It's a method of the `MockRepository` instance, you do not have to create an instance of the mock repository anymore.

To do what you need, use `AssertWasCalled` and `AssertWasNotCalled`.

```
mock.Stub(x => x.Foo()).Return("blah");

unitUnderTest.DoIt();

mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Bar());
```

Comment: can I use only AssertWasCalled(x => x.Bar()); instead of mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Bar()); ?

Comment: How should this work, when there is no instance where you can call `.Bar()` on?